# Using map on returned graphql query is making known members undefined

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm using [Gatsbyjs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) to build a blog and I can't use the [onCreatePage API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onCreatePage) to pass data from my graphql query into page templates.

My query grabs data from [Kentico Cloud](https://kenticocloud.com/) and it looks like this.

```
{
    allKenticoCloudTypeBlogPost{
        edges{
            node{
                contentItems{
                    elements{
                        url_slug{
                            value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a valid query and it returns data that looks like this.

[image: Graphql returned query]

The problem comes in my gatsby-node.js file where I want to utilize this query to build out pages using my predefined template.

Specifically in the createPage method which looks like this.

```
result.data.allKenticoCloudTypeBlogPost.edges.map(({node}) => {        
    createPage({
        path: `${node.contentItems.elements.url_slug.value}`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
        context: {
            slug: node.contentItems.elements.url_slug.value,
        }
    })

});
```

The error that displays is the following.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'url_slug' of undefined
>
> - gatsby-node.js:31 result.data.allKenticoCloudTypeBlogPost.edges.map
>     C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Marketing Repos/xxxx/gatsby-node.js:31:57

I decided to investigate doing a `console.table` on `node.contentItems`, as it appears as though the `elements` part is where it gets tripped up.

The result of console.table(node.contentItems) just before the createPage method is this.

[image: table]

It appears that `node.contentItems` has a member called `url_slug` rather than the `elements` member that I expected.

I thought I could then solve my problem by updating my createPage method call like so.

```
result.data.allKenticoCloudTypeBlogPost.edges.map(({node}) => {
    console.table(node.contentItems);

    createPage({
        path: `${node.contentItems.url_slug.value}`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
        context: {
            slug: node.contentItems.url_slug.value,
        }
    })

});
```

But then I get an error saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

I truly don't understand how I can do a table log and see the url_slug member,  but then when I try to access it, it says that it's undefined. All while I know that my query is correct because I can run it in graphiQL and get back the exact data I expect.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your query result, `node.contentItems` is an array, even though you're trying to access it as if it's an object:

```
path: `${node.contentItems.elements.url_slug.value}`,
                           ^^^^^^^^

console.log(contentItems) // [ { elements: {...} }, { elements: {...} }, ... ]
```

I think your confusion probably stems from the way `console.table` display data. It's confusing if you don't already know the shape of your data. Your screenshot says, this object has 4 properties with index 0 -> 3 (so likely an array), each has one property called `elements` (listed on table header), which is an object with the only property `url_slug`.

---

I'm not familiar with KenticoCloud, but maybe your posts are nested in `contentItems`, in which case you should loop over it:

```
result.data.allKenticoCloudTypeBlogPost.edges.map(({node}) => {        
  node.contentItems.forEach(({ elements }) => {
    createPage({
      path: elements.url_slug.value,
      context: { slug: elements.url_slug.value },
      component: ...
    })

  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Derek. This wasn't the answer but you are correct in saying that node.contentItems is an array and I was accessing it like an object. I'll post an update soon with the solution. Turns out I was calling the wrong thing in graphQL. Once I fixed that, my code worked with no changes. I'll post an update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are wrapping node with curly brackets in your map argument?

You might have already tried this, but my first intuition would be to do this instead:

```
result.data.allKenticoCloudTypeBlogPost.edges.map(node => {  

    console.log(node.contentItems)
    createPage({
        path: `${node.contentItems.elements.url_slug.value}`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
        context: {
            slug: node.contentItems.elements.url_slug.value,
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: The curly brackets are unfortunately necessary, as this is how the data is returned: `edges` is an array of object with a single property `node`. I don't like the way it look personally, but it's more convenient than unwrapping the edge in the body of the function.